# Metafor measure argument error

Tags: r, csv

I have calculated effect size and pooled SE in the way that I wanted. Only thing is drawing a forest plot and let metafor calculate the summary effect size. I have over 30 .csv data files to plot separately. When I do that with the following data (below), it plots and calculates summary effect smoothly.

```
DeltaPI            Spooled
-75.35224985    7.618629848
-51.85221078    7.513461236
-37.77455275    7.164279414
```

The line I use is:

```
meta1<-rma(yi=mydata$DeltaPI, sei=mydata$Spooled)
forest(meta1,slab=paste(mydata$Study,mydata$Genotype..Experimental.),showweight=TRUE,alim=c(-100,25),at=c(-100,-50,0,25),xlab="Percentage Change of PI Score",cex=0.7,cex.lab=1,col="red")
```

However, when I try to do same thing with some other .csv files I have, rma gives an error and asks for 'measure' argument to plot the output. And since the measure is already DeltaPI i calculated manually, I don't want to use.

Weirdly, even if I change the data in those don't working files with the one that working properly(3 data rows above), it still gives the same error. Although, the same data works properly in some other .csv file.

So I'm not clear why I am getting the error and what is the solution.

Any comment would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this has nothing to do with the plotting, but occurs when the `rma()` command is run. And it sounds to me that there are issues with how variables are named in the data that you are reading in. Now you are reading in data from `.csv` files, but this is probably what is happening:

```
> library(metafor)
> dat <- data.frame(DeltaP1 = c(.2,.4), Spooled=c(.1,.1))
> rma(dat$DeltaPI, sei=dat$Spooled)

Error in rma(dat$DeltaPi, sei = dat$s) : 
  Specify the desired outcome measure via the 'measure' argument.
```

So, in essence, you should carefully check the variable names.